# How do you run a command line program after compiling with GCC on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

Some of Facebooks programmer puzzles look fun, so I'm trying to get set up to code in C++ on my mac. I decided to try compiling some of my old CS homework with GCC to get started.

My code compiles fine, but when I try to run the executable (called "encrypt") I get this:

```
-bash: encrypt: command not found
```

I checked the permissions on the file and it seems to have execute permission. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current directory isn't in your `$PATH`, so you have to tell the shell to execute `encrypt` in the current directory.

`./encrypt`

or

`/path/to/directory/encrypt`

Comment: `sh` on a binary file tells `cannot execute binary file` here.

Comment: Both of those work. Sweet! I don't remember having to do this back in college on the linux machines. I guessing we were using a different shell or something.

Comment: @Shea - it should behave the same way in Linux too in various shells, since Mac OSX and Linux systems share the same shells. If I were to venture a guess, you might have had `.` in the PATH in the college systems.

Comment: That would make sense. Those directories were set up specifically for programming homework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute it as `./encrypt`

Answer (score 1):

Try ./encrypt rather than encrypt. Bash won't look for executables with relative paths outside the path.